# SQL Query for all systemusers who's organisationunits has a datevalue < ... with pivot table in between

Tags: sql, sql-server, clrstoredprocedure

I have 3 tables,

- `SystemUsers`
- `OrganisationalUnits`
- `UserOrganisationUnits` - Pivot with UserId/OrganisationUnitId foreign keys

All tables have an `Active` bit column and the `OrganisationalUnit` table has a `CoveredTill` `datetime` column.

I want a list of all `UserOrganisationUnits` where `OrganisationalUnit` "CoveredTill" is < x (value doesn't matter as will be set in clr) date and all tables records are active.

So far I've only managed to get unique users from my query so any advice would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT     
   SystemUsers.DisplayName, SystemUsers.Email, 
   OrganisationalUnits.Description, OrganisationalUnits.CoveredTill, 
   OrganisationalUnits.Id, OrganisationalUnits.ParentId, OrganisationalUnits.TypeId
FROM         
   SystemUsers 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   OrganisationalUnits ON SystemUsers.Id = OrganisationalUnits.Id 
INNER JOIN
   UserOrganisationUnits ON SystemUsers.Id = UserOrganisationUnits.Id
WHERE     
   (OrganisationalUnits.Active = 1) 
   AND (SystemUsers.Active = 1) 
   AND (UserOrganisationUnits.Active = 1) 
   AND (OrganisationalUnits.CoveredTill < '2017-03-31 00:00:00.000')
```

I randomly set the date as the above since I manually set the covered till date as "2015-03-31 00:00:00.000" on all OrganisationalUnits "CoveredTill" columns.

My aim is to have a single sql query string which I can use in my clr stored procedure to create a list of all users who need to be emailed because there organisational unit is no longer covered and for said email to include which organisational unit hence why just having a unique list of users isn't sufficient.

I already have the email code so it's just the query I'm having issues with.

Edit:-

I had first approached this as needing 3 separate queries which I guess after a bit more testing I'll have to revisit unless someone can spot what I'm doing wrong with the above query?

Edit 2:-

After working through the issue with sarin and preparing to provide him a sql db/query copy I found that some of the joins were pointing towards the wrong ID fields (automatically created from different panes so always be wary of anything they create) so below I've included the final solution. (Which includes a couple extra fields I decided might be useful).

```
SELECT  OrganisationalUnits.Description, OrganisationalUnits.CoveredTill, SystemUsers.DisplayName, SystemUsers.Email, 
        UserOrganisationUnits.LastVisited AS UOULastVisited, SystemUsers.LastVisited AS SULastVisited
FROM    UserOrganisationUnits INNER JOIN
        OrganisationalUnits ON UserOrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitId = OrganisationalUnits.Id INNER JOIN
        SystemUsers ON UserOrganisationUnits.UserId = SystemUsers.Id
WHERE   (OrganisationalUnits.Active = 1) AND (SystemUsers.Active = 1) AND (UserOrganisationUnits.Active = 1) AND 
        (OrganisationalUnits.CoveredTill < '2017-03-31 00:00:00.000')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a Right\left join before you do an inner join can give you unexpected results as it may produce nulls and your inner join will then attempt to filter them out. I'm not entirely clear about the relationships between the tables but can you turn them all into INNER JOINS to get the same list and produce you a similar result based on your expected outcome?

"My aim is.... to create a list of all users who need to be emailed because there organisational unit is no longer covered"

UPDATED:

```
SELECT     
   SystemUsers.DisplayName, SystemUsers.Email, 
   OrganisationalUnits.Description, OrganisationalUnits.CoveredTill, 
   OrganisationalUnits.Id, OrganisationalUnits.ParentId, OrganisationalUnits.TypeId
FROM         
   UserOrganisationUnits
INNER JOIN SystemUsers ON SystemUsers.Id = UserOrganisationUnits.Id
                       AND (SystemUsers.Active = 1) 

INNER JOIN OrganisationalUnits ON OrganisationalUnits.Id = SystemUsers.Id
                               AND OrganisationalUnits.Active = 1
                               AND OrganisationalUnits.CoveredTill < '2017-03-31 00:00:00.000'

WHERE UserOrganisationUnits.Active = 1
```

Comment: Yep this was the query I started out with and gets me the same result set of unique users instead of duplicates.  I'm looking to get all records from the "UserOrganisationUnits" tables which are active and have active matching "SystemUsers"/"OrganisationUnits" with the date condition too although for now thats not as important since the date used won't exclude any records right now.

Comment: I was otherwise just trying to use 3 individual queries and try and combine them to get the same result I'd otherwise do in an MVC project using an edmx. (I've had more experience doing queries on that end rather than directly in sql.

Comment: I've changed the order of the joins to match your comment and also moved the where conditions into the joins to speed things up. But the results will be similar. If that's not giving you what you want I think you are going to need to give some data examples from each table in the question and then an example expected result set.

Comment: I'm guessing for the last line you didn't mean for the "WHERE" clause to then be followed by "AND" and then the active condition?  With removing that "AND" I got the same result of 21 records which I know is incorrect since there are multiple OrgUnits which I've assigned myself too yet only 1 record displayed.  With looking closer at the displayed information I've noticed it's not correctly matching up either since the OrgUnitId and SysUserId are the same when they shouldn't be.

Comment: So as far as I can see for some reason it getting the wrong value and that's breaking the likely output so I'll do some tweaking and see if I can resolve it or at least find out what's causing it.

Comment: Indeed. in which case I don't understand what you are looking for! You will need to give more info\an example for me to assist further

Comment: The whole query seems to be feeding out confusing results with some how displaying the wrong user/organisation details and when just looking at the ID's I've noticed it's ignored certain records which it shouldn't so I'll see what I can do.

Comment: During the process of exported data from the 3 tables I got rid of a bunch of fields then anonymised the data followed with testing out the query and bam it works exactly as it should with now giving me 43 records instead of 21 and it's correctly matched up all the other fields data. So basically something in that database is *****ed and is screwing up the queries. *Frustrated Grown*

Comment: well...is it likely you changed the data in one of the join or filter columns by mistake? Could be something as simple as date formats changing?

Comment: Tried breaking down the process to see exactly where the issue is and found for some reason when adding the tables in the 2nd database it had correctly matched up the ID fields which I hadn't noticed were set incorrectly since both queries were created using a mix of the diagram/criteria/sql panes. I'll post the final solution and mark your answer as correct since you were the only one who tried to help which I very much appreciate.